# pdf page not big enough for all columns

Tags: tables, spacing, siunitx

Running the following code I get a table as shown in the following figure with the last element of headline 3 not fitting into the pdf sheet space and its elements are lost. How can I make sure that the last column also fits into the pdf sheet?

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{geometry}

% Set smaller margins for more space
\geometry{margin=1cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \small % Reduce font size
    \begin{tabular}{*{13}{S}}
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Headline 1}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Headline 2}} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Headline 3}} \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9} \cmidrule(lr){10-13}
        {$\alpha$} & {$F$} & {$T_n$} & {$B_n$} & {$\bar{B}_n$} &{$F$} & {$T_n$} & {$B_n$} & {$\bar{B}_n$}  & {$F$} & {$T_n$} & {$B_n$} & {$\bar{B}_n$}  \\ % Corrected column entry here
        \midrule
        & 16.128 & +8.872 & 16.128 & 1.402 & 1.373 & -146.6 & -137.6 & -137.6 & 1.373 & -146.6 & -137.6 & -17.6  \\
        0.99 & 3.442 & -2.509 & 3.442 & 0.299 & 0.343 & 133.2 & 152.4 & -137.6 & 1.373 & -146.6 & -137.6 & -137.6  \\
        & 0. & -0.429 & 0.993 & 0.086 & 0.08 & 25.6 & 90 & -137.6 & 1.373 & -146.6 & -137.6 & -137.6 \\
        \midrule
        & 0.483 & -0.183 & 0.483 & 0.042 & 0.063 & 22.3 & 122.5 & -137.6 & 1.373 & -146.6 & -137.6 & -137.6  \\
        0.95 & 0.766 & -0.475 & 0.766 & 0.067 & 0.039 & 141.6 & -122 & -137.6 & 1.373 & -146.6 & -137.6 & -137.6 \\
        & 0.624 & +0.365 & 0.624 & 0.054 & 0.04 & -35.7 & 90 & -137.6 & 1.373 & -146.6 & -137.6 & -137.6  \\
        \midrule
        & 0.766 & -0.475 & 0.766 & 0.067 & 0.039 & 141.6 & -122 & -137.6 & 1.373 & -146.6 & -137.6 & -137.6 \\
        0.90 & 0.45 & +0.421 & 0.45 & 0.039 & 0.034 & -69.4 & 110.9 & -137.6 & 1.373 & -146.6 & -137.6 & -137.6 \\
        & 0.598 & -0.597 & 0.598 & 0.052 & 0.025 & 92.3 & -109.3 & -137.6 & 1.373 & -146.6 & -137.6 & -137.6  \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save a lot of space if you would define a suitable table format for each of your `S` columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{geometry}

% Set smaller margins for more space
\geometry{margin=1cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
    \small % Reduce font size
    \begin{tabular}{
    S[table-format=1.2]
    S[table-format=2.3]
    S[table-format=-1.3]
    S[table-format=2.3]
    S[table-format=1.3]
    S[table-format=1.3]
    S[table-format=-3.1]
    S[table-format=-3.1]
    S[table-format=-3.1]
    S[table-format=1.3]
    S[table-format=-3.1]
    S[table-format=-3.1]
    S[table-format=-3.1]
    }
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Headline 1}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Headline 2}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Headline 3}} \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9} \cmidrule(lr){10-13}
        {$\alpha$} & {$F$} & {$T_n$} & {$B_n$} & {$\bar{B}_n$} &{$F$} & {$T_n$} & {$B_n$} & {$\bar{B}_n$}  & {$F$} & {$T_n$} & {$B_n$} & {$\bar{B}_n$}  \\ % Corrected column entry here
        \midrule
        & 16.128 & +8.872 & 16.128 & 1.402 & 1.373 & -146.6 & -137.6 & -137.6 & 1.373 & -146.6 & -137.6 & -17.6  \\
        0.99 & 3.442 & -2.509 & 3.442 & 0.299 & 0.343 & 133.2 & 152.4 & -137.6 & 1.373 & -146.6 & -137.6 & -137.6  \\
        & 0. & -0.429 & 0.993 & 0.086 & 0.08 & 25.6 & 90 & -137.6 & 1.373 & -146.6 & -137.6 & -137.6 \\
        \midrule
        & 0.483 & -0.183 & 0.483 & 0.042 & 0.063 & 22.3 & 122.5 & -137.6 & 1.373 & -146.6 & -137.6 & -137.6  \\
        0.95 & 0.766 & -0.475 & 0.766 & 0.067 & 0.039 & 141.6 & -122 & -137.6 & 1.373 & -146.6 & -137.6 & -137.6 \\
        & 0.624 & +0.365 & 0.624 & 0.054 & 0.04 & -35.7 & 90 & -137.6 & 1.373 & -146.6 & -137.6 & -137.6  \\
        \midrule
        & 0.766 & -0.475 & 0.766 & 0.067 & 0.039 & 141.6 & -122 & -137.6 & 1.373 & -146.6 & -137.6 & -137.6 \\
        0.90 & 0.45 & +0.421 & 0.45 & 0.039 & 0.034 & -69.4 & 110.9 & -137.6 & 1.373 & -146.6 & -137.6 & -137.6 \\
        & 0.598 & -0.597 & 0.598 & 0.052 & 0.025 & 92.3 & -109.3 & -137.6 & 1.373 & -146.6 & -137.6 & -137.6  \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]